# MVC View Model advice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am developing my first MVC app and have a question about ViewModels.

My app has a Home model:

```
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public int Number {..}    << This is not the same as the ID and is displayed on all pages for a Home
    public string Name {..}
    ..
}
```

and a Booking model:

```
{
    public int ID {..}   
    [ForeignKey]
    public int HomeID {..}
    public virtual Home Home {..}
    ...
}
```

The default controllers and views worked fine, but I changed it so that a user can select a 'Book' button next to each Home on the Home>Index view which listed all available.

Then in the Booking > Create controller I build a `HomeBookingsViewModel` which contains the Home ID, Number and then List of *Bookings* for that Home.

In the Booking > Create view I call a partial view and pass `model.Bookings` which get displayed in a table.

Then I use a Form to get new the booking.  To do this I had to modify my `HomeBookingViewModel` (see below) to include *From* and *To* dates, otherwise I had no way of getting these values in the controller.

```
{
    public int HomeID { get; set; }
    public int HomeNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start date")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "End date")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }

}
```

The problem I now have is if the Booking>Create[HttpPost] method detects an error (have to check!) I cannot build a `HomeBookingViewModel` to pass back in the return.

Question: Am I over-complicating things or, if this sounds reasonable, how do I return to the form with errors from the Home>Create[HttpPost] controller which looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "HomeID,FromDate,ToDate,BookedBy")] Booking booking)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if ( (booking.FromDate > booking.ToDate) || (booking.FromDate < DateTime.Today.Date) || (booking.ToDate < DateTime.Today.Date))
        {
            return View(booking);
        }
        db.Bookings.Add(booking);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = booking.StoreID } );
    }

    return View(booking);  << Create view is expecting MyApp.Models.BookingViewModel but this is sending just a Booking
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating `BookingViewModel` which will inhabits Your `Booking` created object.

`BookingViewModel` will also have `Error` (string member will surfice) which will contain the obvious and you could check if `Booking` object that returned is valid or not.

**Example:**

```
class BookingViewModel
{
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    // More members here
}
```

If you already got this class than something similar to the following will serve you more.

```
var bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel
{
    Booking = booking,
    IsValid = ModelState.IsValid
}
return View(bookingViewModel);
```